# Add multiple sliders to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using unslider image slider https://github.com/idiot/unslider

I want to add a second slider to the page. The problem is that navigation .arrows class is the same for both slider__1 and slider__2.

And my question is how to add a second slider?

Thank You.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.slider__1, .slider__2').unslider({
    autoplay: false,
    keys: false,
    dots: false
  });

});

var unslider = $('.slider__1').unslider();
$('.arrows').click(function() {
  var fn = this.className.split(' ')[1];
  unslider.data('unslider')[fn]();
});
```

Comment: do the arrows get put inside the slider?  if so you may be able to target them: `.slider__2 .arrows`

Comment: Thank you. I can target arrows now, but I can't add the second slider to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following approach:

1) Add separate class for each set of arrow like follows:

For slider 1:

```
<a href="#" class="arrows prev unslider1">Previous slide</a>
<a href="#" class="arrows next unslider1">Next slide</a>
```

For slider 2:

```
<a href="#" class="arrows prev unslider2">Previous slide</a>
<a href="#" class="arrows next unslider2">Next slide</a>
```

Then inside click event; grab the slider reference as:

```
var unslider1 = $('.slider__1').unslider();
var unslider2 = $('.slider__2').unslider();
$('.arrows').click(function() {
  var fn = this.className.split(' ')[1];
  var sliderRef = this.className.split(' ')[2];
  var unslider = null;
  if(sliderRef  == "unslider1")
      unslider = unslider1 ;
  else
      unslider = unslider2 ;

  unslider.data('unslider')[fn]();
});
```

Hope, this will help you.